# Use of climate and its derivatives as adjectivized forms with another noun

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences, synonyms

I am working on the area of Ecology and the word climate and its derivatives show up in almost every writing.

**Climate/climatic/climatology/climatological**

My question is, what is the correct word to go with nouns such as data, records, archive, etc.? Do they mean the same? Is it just a way to use synonymy to avoid repetition of the word climate in the same piece of writing?

Examples:

- It was the wettest spring in the climat* records
- This database reads historical climat* data
- There is need for a climat* study of this region
- The climat* archives were scrutinised to find missing records

Comment: I'd use *climate* or even better *climatological*, but not the others.

Comment: *Climate* and *climatology* are only ever nouns, never adjectives. Only *climatic* and *climatological* are adjectives.

Comment: @tchrist out of interest, what function does the first noun play in NPs like *climate data*, *weather records*, *university student*, *car tyres*? It seems to be modifying the second noun, even if it's not an adjective.

Comment: No problem in using a noun as an adjunct to another noun -- technically it's a noun but functionally it **is** an adjective in that position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It was the wettest spring in the **climatological** records.
- This database reads historical **climate** data
- There is need for a **climate/climatological** study of this region
- The **climatological** archives were scrutinised to find missing records

Records, including archives, contain data provided by the weather bureau and are "climatological data" as they provide climatological figures for further interpretation and use.

Climate data is figures for the climate. It could be from the weather bureau but that is irrelevant to context. So it's just climate data.

You could study the climate of a region, which is climatology. So both climate study and climatological study are fine.

Note that all "climatological data" is not "climate data." Usually it contains more than plain climate data.